# Split array from a given range

Tags: c#, arrays, split

What is the C# code to split an array from a given range.
Eg:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
```

I want to split `arr` it into two arrays. One from 0th to 5th index and the other from 6th to 20th index.

In Java `Arrays.copyOfRange()` can be used for this process. What is the C# code for this?

Comment: `arr.Take(5).ToArray()` and `arr.Skip(5).ToArray()`

Comment: Since this is a duplicate i've answered there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43491049/284240 In general `Array.Copy` is more efficient than enumerating the array until you are at given indexes and create a new with `ToArray`. For small arrays this is micro-optimization. But since the ugly `Array.Copy` is hidden in an extension method you don't need to care about readable code.

Answer (score 6):

Try using *Linq*:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

 int[] head = arr.Take(5).ToArray();
 int[] tail = arr.Skip(5).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I want to take elements from index 5 to index 10 and make a new array. Is there a direct method.

Comment: @ANJ: To take items from index 5 to 10 just combine `Skip` and `Take`: `int[] middle = arr.Skip(5).Take(5).ToArray();`